# C# Object Constructor Overloads

Tags: c#, constructor

I'm trying to have an overloaded constructor for a class. I think this should be fairly simple, however I can't seem to make it work.

Any ideas?

```
    public SaveFile(string location)
    {
        // Constructor logic here
        //TODO: Implement save event.
        this.Save(location);
    }

    public SaveFile()
    {
        string location = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "\\SaveFile.DAT";
        SaveFile(location);
    }
```

This doesn't compile correctly, and I can't figure out how to do make it work.

Comment: "This doesn't compile correctly" what error are you getting?

Comment: Others have addressed the specific issue of chaining constructors. What I would like to add is a design critique. It feels very wrong to be calling a Save() method from a constructor. Constructors should really do as little as possible other than initializing the object.

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify earlier. The Class is named SaveFile. It's just a serializable form of the data structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the wrong syntax for calling an overloaded constructor from within the default constructor.
To call an overloaded constructor in the same class, use this syntax:

```
public ClassName(parameters) : this(otherParameters)
{
   // logic
}
```

If you wanted to call a constructor in the base class, then you would use the `base` keyword instead of `this`. In your case the code would read:

```
public SaveFile() : this(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "SaveFile.DAT") {}
public SaveFile(string location)
{
    this.Save(location);
}
```

Comment: See! I knew it was something simple that I was missing!

Answer (score 2):

```
 public SaveFile() 
   : this(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "\\SaveFile.DAT")
    { 
    }
```

However that really should be:

```
 public SaveFile() 
   : this(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),"SaveFile.DAT"))
    { 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public SaveFile(string location)
{
    // Constructor logic here
    //TODO: Implement save event.
    this.Save(location);
}

public SaveFile(): this(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "\\SaveFile.DAT")
{
}
```